# Jquery .Post Return Elements that I can use

Tags: jquery, html

This may be simple for some but, I'm having some major trouble here.

```
$.post("ajax.php?returntable=1", { }, function(data)
{
    $("#output<?=$tabindex?>").html(data);
    buttoncontrol(joborder, opno, employee, "StartProduction");
}, "html");
```

This outputs the HTML data from php page into DIV and works fine.

The data contains multiple input boxes with a specific class - attributes are with it to return data.

```
echo "<input style='text-align:right; width:90px;' type='number' class='laborlinechange' foperno='".trim($rs->fields['foperno'])."' joborder = '".trim($rs->fields['fjobno'])."' datetimed = '".$rs->fields['datetime']."' changetype = 'startcount' value='".$rs->fields['fstartcount']."'>";
```

my question is when I go to access the classes without refreshing it won't let me.

```
$(".laborlinechange").blur(function (e) 
{
     alert("ANYTHING");
})
```

I don't know if I need to .addClass or what I need to do exactly.
I think somewhere I need to tell the elements to create but, don't know where or how:(
Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

On dynamic element, you need to use event delegation :

```
$(document).on('blur', ".laborlinechange", function (e) 
{
    alert("ANYTHING");
});
```

An other solution is to bind the event after you have created it. Performance wise, this solution is better, but it is harder to control it and may duplicate your code :

```
$("#output<?=$tabindex?>").html(data)
.find('.laborlinechange').on('blur', function(){
    alert('yeah');
});
buttoncontrol(joborder, opno, employee, "StartProduction");
```

You'll find more information here : https://api.jquery.com/on/#direct-and-delegated-events

Searching on google on the subject of *delegation*, *dynamics element* and combination of *ajax / event* will show you a lot of information on the subject : [event + dynamic + element](https://www.google.ca/search?q=event+dynamics+element&oq=event+dynamics+element&aqs=chrome..69i57j0l3.7937j0j1&sourceid=chrome&espv=210&es_sm=119&ie=UTF-8)

Answer (score 1):

If you are adding elements to the DOM dynamically, they will not have event listeners attached to them that get added by jQuery when you use:

```
$(function () {
  $(".laborlinechange").blur(function (e) 
  {
       alert("ANYTHING");
  });
}
```

Your `blur` code was only applied to elements that existed at the time the jQuery code was run (which was when the document was ready (technically, `$(function() {})` does not run when the document is ready, but you get the idea)).

The easiest way is to apply the event listener after the DOM is updated:

```
$.post("ajax.php?returntable=1", { }, function(data)
{
    $("#output<?=$tabindex?>").html(data);
    $("#output<?=$tabindex?> .laborlinechange").blur(function (e) 
    {
         alert("ANYTHING");
    });
    //...
```

Another solution is to use event delegation as per @Karl-André_Gagnon's answer.

Answer (score 0):

In JQuery, the default binding such as `.click, .change, .blur` etc etc are only bound to the initial DOM content. Since you are ajaxing in new content, the JQuery bindings don't see that new content. Try the following instead.

`$(document).on("blur", ".laborlinechange", function({ //code });`

Answer (score 0):

Your event handler will be bound to listen for the blur event, but only for the elements that are present on the page when it originally loads. There is some inconsistency with jQuery's event handlers and whether they listen through AJAX loads or simply for the original page load, but you can use the `on` or `delegate` binding to ensure they will listen after AJAX calls are complete:

```
$(document).on('blur', '.laborlinechange', function(e) {
    alert("ANYTHING");
});
```

**Docs:** https://api.jquery.com/on/